# Issue with String.Format() - FormatException

Tags: c#, string.format, formatexception

I am trying to make a simple shotgun game where the user vs the CPU and the both pick shot, shield or reload but it displays the results I get the error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index (zero based) must be greater than or
>   equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.

```
//Declare Variables
int CPUBullets = 3, userBullets = 3;
ShotgunOption UserOption;
ShotgunOption CPUOption;
int userScore = 0;
int CPUscore = 0;
double gameCount = 0.0;
Random computer = new Random();

Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("Welcome To The Shotgun Game");
Console.WriteLine("SHOOT RELOAD SHIELD");



do
{

    // Prompt User/ Get Random Value From CPU
    //Console.Write("Best of 5, Please enter choice: ");
    UserOption = GetOptionFromUser();
    CPUOption = (ShotgunOption)computer.Next(1, 3); // 1 is Shot, 2 is Reload, 3 is Shield




    switch (UserOption)
    {
        case ShotgunOption.Shoot:
            if ((int)CPUOption == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Shoot. It was a tie!", UserOption);
                ; userBullets--; CPUBullets--;
                Console.ReadLine();
                DisplayResults(UserOption, CPUOption, userScore, userBullets, CPUBullets);
            }
            else if ((int)CPUOption == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Reload. You win!", UserOption);
                ++userScore; ++gameCount;
                Console.ReadLine();
                DisplayResults(UserOption, CPUOption, userScore, userBullets, CPUBullets);
            }
            else if ((int)CPUOption == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Shield. It's a draw!", UserOption);
                ++gameCount;
                Console.ReadLine();
                DisplayResults(UserOption, CPUOption, userScore, userBullets, CPUBullets);
            }
            break;
        case ShotgunOption.Reload:
            if ((int)CPUOption == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Shoot. You lose!", UserOption);
                 ++gameCount; ++CPUscore;
                Console.ReadLine();
                DisplayResults(UserOption, CPUOption, userScore, userBullets, CPUBullets);
            }
            else if ((int)CPUOption == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Reload. You Both Gain A bullet", UserOption);
                userBullets++; CPUBullets++; ++gameCount;
                Console.ReadLine();
                DisplayResults(UserOption, CPUOption, userScore, userBullets, CPUBullets);
            }
            else if ((int)CPUOption == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Shield. It's a draw!", UserOption);
                DisplayResults(UserOption, CPUOption, userScore, userBullets, CPUBullets);

            }
            break;
        case ShotgunOption.Shield:
            if ((int)CPUOption == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Shoot. It's a draw!", UserOption);
                ++gameCount;
                Console.ReadLine();
                DisplayResults(UserOption, CPUOption, userScore, userBullets, CPUBullets);
            }
            else if ((int)CPUOption == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Reload. You win!", UserOption);
                ++userScore; ++gameCount;
                Console.ReadLine();
                DisplayResults(UserOption, CPUOption, userScore, userBullets, CPUBullets);
            }
            else if ((int)CPUOption == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You chose {0} and the computer chose Shield. It's a draw!", UserOption);
                ++gameCount;
                Console.ReadLine();
                DisplayResults(UserOption, CPUOption, userScore, userBullets, CPUBullets);
            }
            break;

    }


} while (gameCount < 4);
```

And here's the `DisplayResults()` method were the error happens:

```
static void DisplayResults(ShotgunOption UserOption, ShotgunOption CPUOption, int UserScore, int UserBullets, int CPUBullets)
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Round Over");
    Console.WriteLine("You Chose {0}, The Computer Chose{1} Your Score is {3} . You had {4} Bullet(s). The CPU had {5} bullets(s).", UserOption, CPUOption, UserScore, UserBullets, CPUBullets);
    Console.WriteLine("Thanks for playing!"); 
    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Comment: Just a quick point - `computer.Next(1, 3)` returns either `1` or `2` - it does **not** return `3`. The second parameter is an **exclusive upper bound**.

Comment: I had a play with your code and created you this version of your code - https://dotnetfiddle.net/Xt1KI0. You might want to have a play as this type of coding reduces a lot of the repetition that you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format string is missing an index (specifically, position **2**):

```
"You Chose {0}, The Computer Chose{1} Your Score is {3} . You had {4} Bullet(s). The CPU had {5} bullets(s)."
                                                    ^^^
```

Should be:

```
"You Chose {0}, The Computer Chose{1} Your Score is {2} . You had {3} Bullet(s). The CPU had {4} bullets(s)."
```